# Broken image in richtext field

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

In my app I have a richtext field in which I display text and I want to display images too. The images are being displayed perfectly on my local PC, I also have a test server installed on my local PC and that works too.
But when I create a document on the production server, the image is not displayed. Firefox hides it completely and Chrome shows broken image link.

This is the created url on local machine:

```
http://localhost:86/Folder/Folder/myapp.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-3-Body/_2_07B23E640790993000318CC8C1257A05.jpeg
```

This is the url on the server:

```
http://domain.mk/Folder/myapp.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-59-Body/_2_06176AD0070E4830003325DCC1257A05.jpeg
```

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Does the "Folder" name on the server contain spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally have sorted this out. It has something to do with the caching or whatnot. If you open the document in the browser right after saving it in Notes, it acts like the image is not actually uploaded. So I refreshed the page after 1-2 minutes and the image is there.

Answer (score 0):

Is your image available for anonymous users? Can it be that the access to the file is the problem?

Comment: How can I check that? If you mean in the ACL, anonymous has author access.